# Integration of application with HashiCorp Vault

Tags: hashicorp-vault

I have been exploring HashiCorp vault for PoC purpose for a week. I am trying to design a very simple system where an application logs in to the vault using a **role_id** and **secret_id** which has life-time validity and requests for unique one-time use database credentials. I have successfully integrated the database with the vault and upon passing a policy-generated token, new credentials (username & password) are created for the intended user.

Now, I have successfully generated the role_id and secrete_id for the application too, and when I am passing this command from within the vault environment, I am getting a token for the credentials generation.

```
/ # vault write auth/approle/login role_id="9805c2d7-db84-f17f-843a-440e5a797254" secret_id="1cebcd60-5de5-b0a7-f43c-3df69ae274a4"

Key                     Value
---                     -----
token                   s.fMjSkiloNdkNcRPGQfjmzjGN
token_accessor          orQymBllwi81KEXvpKn6cELq
token_duration          1h
token_renewable         true
token_policies          ["apps" "default"]
identity_policies       []
policies                ["apps" "default"]
token_meta_role_name    app-login
```

After which the following command generates the unique credentials:

```
/ # VAULT_TOKEN=s.fMjSkiloNdkNcRPGQfjmzjGN vault read database/creds/readonly
Key                Value
---                -----
lease_id           database/creds/readonly/FD71umy2l3Vd02iIc6ACtumz
lease_duration     1h
lease_renewable    true
password           A1a-KFjVbJQ9DsUwYQ6r
username           v-approle-readonly-mhQ73CzTWBTgVptBmZbh-1600158851
```

Following which I have sealed the vault:

```
Vault operator seal
```

But now when I am trying to pass the role_id and secret_id using the earlier command to generate a token, it's showing that the vault is sealed:

```
/ # vault write auth/approle/login role_id="9805c2d7-db84-f17f-843a-440e5a797254" secret_id="1cebcd60-5de5-b0a7-f43c-3df69ae274a4"
Error writing data to auth/approle/login: Error making API request.

URL: PUT http://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/auth/approle/login
Code: 503. Errors:

* error performing token check: Vault is sealed
```

So, is it that the application has to first unseal the vault by any means and then only it can ask for the credentials? And, if that's the way, then doesn't unsealing it defeat the whole purpose of using the vault?

All suggestions to my issue are welcome.

**Important Note:** I am not using any orchestrator or configuration management tool. The use case is fairly simple. I want to hard code the role_id and secret_id in the application code.

Comment: sealing Vault is an operator-level operation, not application. I recommend you go through the [seal/unseal concept docs](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/concepts/seal).

Comment: @Marc, I have gone through the same. My question is, can an application interact with a sealed vault. If so how?

Comment: It can't, the operator needs to unseal it first.

Comment: @Mac, OK I get it now. But sir, I have a doubt, if unsealing the vault is a primary requirement for any application to interact with vault, then doesn't that defeat the whole purpose of putting the secret in vault? I mean, from what I understand of it; when a vault is sealed, the data within is encrypted. Now, my question is if it is left in unsealed position, isn't the data vulnerable?

Comment: No, it is still encrypted at the storage level, it just means that the vault node has the key loaded in memory and can decrypt the contents. When it is sealed, the vault node cannot decrypt anything.

Comment: @Mac, Thanks a lot for the help Sir!